# Escape case sensitive file names for HFS+

Tags: python

I wish to store files in a temp folder before I upload them to a server. I am using multiprocessing and it is possible that I save the file: OBrien.png and Obrien.png to the temp folder at the same time. How might I escape the file name so that I can save both filenames despite using a HFS+ formatted drive. I could create a hash for each filename but it would be nice if the filenames were readable for debugging purposes.

Comment: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CaseFoldingPlan